# Silverman proposition I.2.6 part c

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm reading Silverman's book the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. I don't know how to prove part c of proposition I.2.6 on page 10.

> **Proposition 2.6.** (c) If an affine variety $V$ is defined over $K$, then $\overline{V}$ is also defined over $K$. (Here $\overline{V}$ is the projective closure of $V$.)

What I tried so far: I know that $I(V)=(S)$ for some $S$ containing polynomials over $K$. But by definition of $\overline{V}$, $I(\overline{V})=(f^{*}:f\in I(V))$, where $f^{*}$ is the homogenization of $f$ with respect to $X_{i}$. I'm guessing that $I(\overline{V})=(f^{*}:f\in S)$. So I'm trying to prove $(f^{*}:f\in I(V))=(f^{*}:f\in S)$. Let $(f_{1}g_{1}+\cdots+f_{m}g_{m})^{*}\in LHS$, where $f_{i}\in S$. I cannot move the * inside. I have to multiply by some powers of $X_{i}$. So I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You should add that $f^*$ is the homogenisation of $f$, and $\overline{V}$ is the projective closure.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Your claim is not true for an arbitrary generating set $S$.  The twisted cubic curve is an example of this: the affine curve corresponds to the ideal $(y - x^2, z - x^3)$, but its projective closure does *not* correspond to $(wy - x^2, w^2z - x^3)$.  If you choose $S$ to be a Gröbner basis for $I(V)$ with respect to a graded monomial ordering, then the claim is true.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thank you. I have to read what a Grobner basis is and what a graded monomial ordering is.

Comment: @Delong I doubt that Silverman expects you to use Gröbner bases to prove this, so there must be another way.  I just didn't want you wasting your time trying to prove something that isn't true.  Why can't you just work directly with $(f^* : f \in I(V))$?  Homogenizing doesn't change the fact that the coefficients are in $K$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Because not every polynomial in $I(V)$ has coefficients in $K$.

Comment: Did you find a solution without Gröbner bases?

Comment: @psl2Z no, I didn't